# Android: Adding Spinner dynamically in one activity doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have an Activity with a TimePicker, a Spinner with a list of aliments and a button. When I press a button, I want to add dynamically a Spinner to the view.

This is my button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Aggiungi un altro alimento"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:onClick="addAnotherAliment"/>
```

And this the related method called after onClick event

```
public void addAnotherAliment(View view) {
    Spinner alimentSpinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> alimentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.aliments)
    );
    alimentSpinner.setAdapter(alimentAdapter);
    LinearLayout containerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    containerLayout.addView(alimentSpinner);
}
```

But i get "Unfortunately, your app has stopped". What's wrong?

This is the entire Activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        populateFirstSpinner();
    }

    private void populateFirstSpinner() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Spinner spinnerAliments = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.alimenti);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerCountAliments = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.aliments));
        spinnerAliments.setAdapter(spinnerCountAliments);
    }

    public void addAnotherAliment(View view) {
        Spinner alimentSpinner = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> alimentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.aliments)
        );
        alimentSpinner.setAdapter(alimentAdapter);
        LinearLayout containerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container_registration);
        containerLayout.addView(alimentSpinner);
    }


}
```

Logcat says:

```
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 0 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 1 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 2 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 3 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 4 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 5 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 6 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 7 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 8 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 9 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 10 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 11 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 12 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 13 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 14 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 15 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 16 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 17 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 18 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 19 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 20 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 21 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 22 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 23 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 24 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 25 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 26 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 27 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 28 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 29 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 30 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 31 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 32 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
11-05 18:05:21.002    1113-1113/com.android.defcontainer W/dalvikvm﹕ PR_CAPBSET_DROP 33 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
```

Comment: can you post Cat log error ? , or replace `this` on `new ArrayAdapter` to `context` or `classname.class`

Comment: The logcat you posted is useless, capture the errors being thrown that are RELEVANT to your code.

Comment: I know, but logcat contains ONLY that after crash. I can create a repository on github if someone agree =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check it. Make a linear or any other layout that is required in you program.

```
public Spinner addNewSpinner(int id, String[] vals) {

    sp = new Spinner(this);
    sp.setId(id);


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, vals);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource((R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item));
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    linearLayout.addView(sp);

    return sp;
}
```

Comment: why you dont declare isNew, sp, adapter and so on?

Comment: the variable was declared as class variable. it is obvious that you need to declare variables before use.